# Dynamic adding and removing elements from Widget list

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I want to create a list of widgets(TextFormField) in which I can add a new element with button Add, and remove any element with the button next to that element. So I would have unknown number of TextFormFields in array and would be able to add a new one, and destroy any one TextFormField.

I was able to make adding of new TextFormFields but removing only works if I want to remove last one.
Is there any way to determine the index of removeButton that was clicked?

```
List<Widget> proba = new List<Widget>();
List<TextEditingController> _controllers = new List<TextEditingController>();

...

IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controllers.add(new TextEditingController());
            });
            setState(() {
              proba.add(Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.radio_button_unchecked),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _controllers[_controllers.length - 1],
                      decoration:
                          InputDecoration(hintText: "Add text..."),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _controllers.removeAt(_controllers.length - 1);
                        proba.removeAt(proba.length - 1);
                      });
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ));
            });
          },
        ),
```

Adding works fine. The code removes last element but I would like to remove the element whose button was clicked.

[image: This is how it looks on screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use a ListView (for example with the builder constructor), so that each Row is a ListTile. The itemBuilder builds the item and you have access to the index. It would look something like this:

```
int itemCount = 3;
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _counter,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.radio_button_unchecked),
        title: TextFormField(),
        trailing: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _counter--;
            });
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

In the setState Method in the onPressed property you have access to the index. In the example the ListView takes care to create the ListTiles based on the itemCount. You might want to create a list of objects instead of just the int itemCount to store data (maybe the text in the TextFormField). But you can still delete the item based on the index from the itemBuilder: values.deleteAt(index).

Have a look at the docs for the ListView and the ListTile classes:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html